# How to get some Specific data from Restapi [flutter]

Tags: android, flutter, rest, dart

**I want to get only those item which contain type Lunch** `` **This is a function where I can fetch data from Rest Api and also ApiResponse added**

I need to get specific data from a session I send instead of getting the entire array from the response from the Api() method. How do I capture just the  only those item which contain type Lunch from the array?

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Snack",
      "type": "breakfast",
      "detail": "18",
      "image": "uploads/Screenshot_2022-12-04-13-15-13-27.jpg",
      "carbs": 6,
      "proteins": 4,
      "fats": 8,
      "cal": 4,
      "day": 1,
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "Chicken",
      "type": "lunch",
      "detail": "White Chicken",
      "image": "uploads/1670258808164716637219.jpg",
      "carbs": 15,
      "proteins": 18,
      "fats": 10,
      "cal": 200,
      "day": 1,
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "546e57rufjvjv",
      "type": "lunch",
      "detail": "gdyhj",
      "image": "uploads/meat.png",
      "carbs": 6578,
      "proteins": 2345,
      "fats": 5678,
      "cal": 4325,
      "day": 5,
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "name": "Anda Tikki",
      "type": "dinner",
      "detail": "Egg and Daal",
      "image": "uploads/1670259245043112842388.jpg",
      "carbs": 10,
      "proteins": 8,
      "fats": 12,
      "cal": 180,
      "day": 1,
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "name": "Boiled egg and cucumber",
      "type": "breakfast",
      "detail": "Egg and cucumber",
      "image": "uploads/1670259362662817976982.jpg",
      "carbs": 10,
      "proteins": 5,
      "fats": 5,
      "cal": 100,
      "day": 2,
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null
    }
  ],
  "message": "Food Data retrieved successfully."
}
```

```
Future<List<ProductsModel>> getProducts({String? query}) async {
    List<ProductsModel> products = [];
    var data=[];
    try {
      String url = 'https://diet.appetitor.app/Celo/api/user/food/2000.0';
      var response = await Dio().get(url,
          options: Options(headers: {
            HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
          }));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
     
        products.clear(); 
        ProductsModel.fromJson(response.data);
        products.add(ProductsModel.fromJson(response.data));
          if (query != null) {
            print(products.length);
         
          products = products
              .map((e) { 
                e.data!.where((element) => element.type!.toLowerCase().contains('lunch'));
              })
              .cast<ProductsModel>()
              .toList();
        }

         
      }
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e.response);
    }
    return products;
  }
}
```

Comment: if you have access to the rest API,  modify the API with a query param (https://diet.appetitor.app/Celo/api/user/food/2000.0/type='lunch' ). It will save time, bandwidth, server & device resources.

Answer (score 0):

If the response status code returns 200 after making a request with the rest api, assign the data in it to a variable of the type of your model, then you can get it from the variable as you want.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).